# TEXT Deforming Separetor lines

Tags: qt, qml

I need the text in qml app looks like
In below not in image

[image: THE SEPARETOR LINE DEFORMED]

```
ID  EXT  RESOLUTION FPS |  FILESIZE     TBR PROTO | VCODEC        VBR 
--- ---- ---------- --- - ----------- ----- ----- - ----------- ----- 
139 m4a  audio only     |  355.74KiB    48k https |                   
249 webm audio only     |  404.19KiB    55k https |                   
250 webm audio only     |  526.19KiB    72k https |                   
140 m4a  audio only     |  942.33KiB   129k https |                   
251 webm audio only     |  1011.70KiB  139k https |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a monospace font like "monospace" or "Courier New":

```
Text{
    text: "ID  EXT  RESOLUTION FPS |  FILESIZE     TBR PROTO | VCODEC        VBR
--- ---- ---------- --- - ----------- ----- ----- - ----------- -----
139 m4a  audio only     |  355.74KiB    48k https |
249 webm audio only     |  404.19KiB    55k https |
250 webm audio only     |  526.19KiB    72k https |
140 m4a  audio only     |  942.33KiB   129k https |
251 webm audio only     |  1011.70KiB  139k https |                    "
    font.family: "monospace"
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ,, But still the same

Comment: i using windows , i putted the text in rectangle ,https://ar.images.guru/i/3oX1f

Comment: @AmmarAlshathry I do not want the image of the code but of the output window. Also try `font.family: "Courier New"`

Comment: YES , the second one Worked Thanks Brother For Help...

Comment: @AmmarAlshathry please review the [tour]